# How does google.com handle the web traffic with just one IP?

Tags: dns, ip

I ran nslookup on google.com.
Only one IP is returned.
How does google.com handle the web traffic with just one IP?

```
nslookup google.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.194.174
```

In contrast, a lookup on stackoverflow.com returned 4 IP addresses.

```
nslookup www.stackoverflow.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.stackoverflow.com   canonical name = stackoverflow.com.
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Google maintains the IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as the primary and secondary DNS addresses for Google Public DNS. A network of DNS servers strategically located around the world support queries at these addresses.

The following public IP address ranges belong to Google.com:
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255

Comment: Do you mean different people in different parts of the world running "nslookup google.com" will get a different Google IP returned?  In my case, I'm getting 216.58.194.174.

Comment: Btw, the Google IP (216.58.194.174) I got from nslookp doesn't fall in one of the IP ranges you listed.

Comment: yes buddy its correct when you run from diff location you will get the diff IP.